# RXJS data manipulation

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs

I am trying to find the reactive way of manipulating data in an array of objects.  In the array below, I want to determine the low score in groups of four and add a low and diff property to the item.

```
arr = [
    { name: 'Cliff', score: 44 },
    { name: 'Bob', score: 55 },
    { name: 'Jack', score: 404 },
    { name: 'John', score: 50 },
    { name: 'Doug', score: 22 },
    { name: 'EZ', score: 550 },
    { name: 'Bill', score: 404 },
    { name: 'Dan', score: 5 },
    { name: 'Rich', score: 404 },
    { name: 'Steve', score: 565 },
  ];
  arr$: Observable<Arr[]> = of(this.arr);

  getData() {
    const scores = this.arr$.pipe(
      map((result) =>
        result.map((data) => {
          return {
            x: data.score,
          };
        })
      )
      // reduce((acc, x) => (acc = acc > x.score ? acc :x.score), 0)
    );

    return scores;
  }
}

/*
Desired result
arr = [
  { name: 'Cliff', score: 44, low: 44, diff 0 },
  { name: 'Bob', score: 55, low: 44, diff: 9 },
  { name: 'Jack', score: 404, low 44, diff: 360 },
  { name: 'John', score: 50, low: 44, diff: 6 },
  { name: 'Doug', score: 22, low 5, diff: 17 },
  { name: 'EZ', score: 550, low 5, diff: 545 },
  { name: 'Bill', score: 404, low 5, diff: 399 },
  { name: 'Dan', score: 5, low 5, diff: 0 },
  { name: 'Rich', score: 404, low: 404, diff: 0 },
  { name: 'Steve', score: 565. low 404, diff: 121 },
];
*/
```

I can't seem to get past the few lines of code that I've written.  A StackBlitz is [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e5l4hd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: don't the data need to be sorted by score first?

Answer (score 4):

This could be a reactive way to get what you want. The comments in the code explain the logic.

```
// the from rxjs function takes an array and returns an 
// Observable that emits each item in the array
from(arr)
  .pipe(
    // bufferCount will emit an array of arrays of items,
    // therefore creates the groups of four items
    bufferCount(4),
    // for each group we find the low and create 
    // the new items with the low value and the diff
    map((buff) => {
      const low = buff.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return acc < curr.score ? acc : curr.score;
      }, Infinity);
      return buff.map((v) => ({ ...v, low, diff: v.score - low }));
    }),
    // with mergeMap we flatten the groups of items 
    // and emit each item
    mergeMap((buffEnriched) => buffEnriched),
   // if you want to emit an array rather than each single
   // object you add toArray
   toArray()
  )
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have updated the StackBlitz to your answer.  Do you have a good source to learn reactive design patterns?  What I find online rarely goes much beyond the use of each operator.

Answer (score 0):

it makes more sense to sort, then generate your data. otherwise, your output data in your question makes little sense to me.

```js
// DATA IN
arr = [
    { name: 'Cliff', score: 44 },
    { name: 'Bob', score: 55 },
    { name: 'Jack', score: 404 },
    { name: 'John', score: 50 },
    { name: 'Doug', score: 22 },
    { name: 'EZ', score: 550 },
    { name: 'Bill', score: 404 },
    { name: 'Dan', score: 5 },
    { name: 'Rich', score: 404 },
    { name: 'Steve', score: 565 },
  ];
 
// PROCESSING and OUTPUT
let lowest = arr[0].score;
let output_arr = arr.sort((a, b)=>{
    if(a.score < b.score) return -1;
    if(a.score > b.score) return 1;
  return 0;
}).map((a)=>{
    if(a.score < lowest) lowest = a.score;
        return {
        name: 'Steve',
      score: 565,
      low: lowest,
      diff: a.score - lowest
     };
});

// use output array output
console.log(output_arr);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/25awt13u/)

## Example

#### INPUT

```
[
    { name: 'Cliff', score: 44 },
    { name: 'Bob', score: 55 },
    { name: 'Jack', score: 404 },
    { name: 'John', score: 50 },
    { name: 'Doug', score: 22 },
    { name: 'EZ', score: 550 },
    { name: 'Bill', score: 404 },
    { name: 'Dan', score: 5 },
    { name: 'Rich', score: 404 },
    { name: 'Steve', score: 565 },
  ]
```

#### OUTPUT

```
[{
  diff: 0,
  low: 5,
  name: "Steve",
  score: 565
}, {
  diff: 17,
  low: 5,
  name: "Steve",
  score: 565
}, {
  diff: 39,
  low: 5,
  name: "Steve",
  score: 565
}, {
  diff: 45,
  low: 5,
  name: "Steve",
  score: 565
}, {
  diff: 50,
  low: 5,
  name: "Steve",
  score: 565
}, {
  diff: 399,
  low: 5,
  name: "Steve",
  score: 565
}, {
  diff: 399,
  low: 5,
  name: "Steve",
  score: 565
}, {
  diff: 399,
  low: 5,
  name: "Steve",
  score: 565
}, {
  diff: 545,
  low: 5,
  name: "Steve",
  score: 565
}, {
  diff: 560,
  low: 5,
  name: "Steve",
  score: 565
}]
```

Comment: The input array reflects two groups of four players and one group of two.  Assume that I want to balance/handicap the next competition among these players.  Sorting the entire array does not work.  Also, I'm trying to learn how to perform the manipulation using Observables.  Your concise declarative answer works, but I don't want to subscribe the the Observable array at this point and thus need a reactive approach similar to @Picci  above.